# Is there any way to highlight a country using Google Maps javascript api, similar to the embed api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I'm wondering if it's possible to automatically highlight a country on Google Maps using the javascript API, similar to the way you can using an embedded map like so:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/United+Kingdom/@55.3617609,-3.4433238,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x25a3b1142c791a9:0xc4f8a0433288257a

My problem is using that, using the embedded solution, I cannot turn off the Google Maps UI, which I can do with the javascript API.

Comment: I don't understand why this was marked as a duplicate. I was looking for an automatic way to do it in a similar fashion to the embed API. What was asked in the linked question isn't how I wanted to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [draw a polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple) over the said country. You'll need the coordinate data for the outline, but there are resources online that have that information, for example [here](http://www.diva-gis.org/Data).